# Undeletable file in cygwin

Tags: cygwin

A command I executed in cygwin hosed up a bunch of files.  Now I cannot delete them.  Omitting most of the 'ls' output, here is what I'm dealing with:

```
% ls -l
ls: cannot access WSERV001.txt: No such file or directory
-rw-r--r--  1 mccppk mkgroup-l-d   50 Sep 17 16:57 WSERV001.text
??????????? ? ?      ?              ?            ? WSERV001.txt
% rm WSERV001.txt
rm: cannot remove `WSERV001.txt': No such file or directory
% touch WSERV001.txt
touch: cannot touch `WSERV001.txt': Permission denied
```

The .text file is normal.  The .txt file (directory entry anyway) is obviously hosed.  Any ideas on how to get the .txt file deleted?

Comment: I had that happen before, but I don't remember which machine did it.  I "wrote it off" as Cygwin not working with NTFS properly.  What OS are you using?

Comment: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming..." So, based on that, I think *does* belong on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attempts to use chown and chmod, even as root, failed (I don't recall the error).

I'm pretty sure my disk is fine.  I run DiskCheckup daily for a strong history of SMART settings, and checked it this morning.  No worries there.

Since the original problem and post, I got busy, and just now got back to that same local shell window.  Those files were gone.  This was a local cygwin shell on my laptop, so I know that no one else "helped".  Strange.  Those .txt files were just not there anymore.

I'm still curious what would cause ls to output all question-marks like that for all of the file metadata, except for the filename.  But the main issue is resolved.

Comment: Easy. File that is failing stat(2) because it isn't really there or has a pending delete operation.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem and fixed it as follow (under Win7):

Open a cmd windows (run as Administrator)

> takeown /r /f DRIVE:\PATH
>
> icacls DRIVE:\PATH /grant USERNAME:F /T

where USERNAME is your win7 username under which you are running this.

Also make sure cron.exe is NOT running for user USERNAME or SYSTEM (can be checked from the TaskManager) and that no programs from cygwin are running.

Once all has been checked and done, you should be able to delete your files.

Hope this helps,

Jean

Comment: Thanks, Jean.  I'm not running Win7, but perhaps your solution will help others who are.

Comment: Worked for me on windows 7 files - I could not delete 2 files owned by jane smith under /etc/group and /etc/passwd, despite being an administrator, but this did the trick!

Comment: Worked for me! Now my cygwin git configured and working!

Comment: Thanks pal. This resolved my problem on Windows 10 as well.

Answer (score 5):

I have a reproducible case and none of what is suggested here helps because of permissions restrictions.

Under sygwin:

```
[Sakis@t0000000000]$ ll
total 0
drwxr-x--- 1 ???????? ???????? 0 Jul  4 02:51 t0000000000_1.db/
[Sakis@t0000000000]$
```

Trying to take the owner from an admin cmd console:

```
c:\t000000000
0>takeown /r /f t0000000000_1.db
ERROR: Access is denied.
```

Trying to delete from an admin cmd console:

```
c:\t000000000
0>rmdir /S t0000000000_1.db
t0000000000_1.db, Are you sure (Y/N)? Y
Access is denied.
```

Cannot also change the owner from the windows GUI. It complains that you should have read permissions.

--- RESOLVED ---

Finally, I have managed to delete it by entering a **cmd** command with **administration** privileges and execute:

```
rm -r <dir>
```

TIP: You have to make sure that the directory in not used at all. You can use the procmon to find you who locks that directory.

Comment: I too had the same problem and none of the previous solutions were working, but this worked. Thanks!

Comment: How did you run up an admin cmd console from Cygwin?

Comment: @UmberFerrule You don't from cygwin - find it using the start menu, right-click and pick "Run as adminaistrator"

Answer (score -1):

As admin, this should fix:

```
chown <yourusername> WSERV001.txt
chmod 666 WSERV001.txt
rm -f WSERV001.txt
```

If not, you might have disk errors.

Comment: chown fails with "Access denied error" message in my case.